# Indexing by traceid and guid[EFK, Elasticsearch, Fluentd]

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, fluentd, efk

I print the logs as follows. I want to index for fields such as traceid, guid. How can I do this with a configuration in fluentd and elasticseeach?

**Java logger**

```
stringBuilder.append("guid=[").append((guid == null ? "" : guid)).append("] ");
stringBuilder.append("traceid=[").append(tracer.currentSpan().context().traceId()).append("] ");
stringBuilder.append("spanid=[").append(tracer.currentSpan().context().spanId()).append("] ");
stringBuilder.append("method=[").append(request.getMethod()).append("] ");
stringBuilder.append("path=[").append(request.getRequestURI()).append("] ");
logger.info(stringBuilder.toString());
```

fluentd configuration file

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  01_sources.conf: |-
    ## logs from podman
    <source>
      @type tail
      @id in_tail_container_logs
      @label @KUBERNETES
      path /var/log/containers/*auth*.log
      pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
      tag kubernetes.*
      read_from_head true
      <parse>
        @type multi_format
        <pattern>
          format json
          time_key time
          time_type string
          time_format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ"
          keep_time_key false
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
          format regexp
          expression /^(?<time>.+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr)( (.))? (?<log>.*)$/
          time_format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ'
          keep_time_key false
        </pattern>
      </parse>
      emit_unmatched_lines true
    </source>
04_outputs.conf: |-
    <label @OUTPUT>
      <match **>
        @type elasticsearch
        host "elasticsearch-master"
        port 9200
        user elastic
        index_name fluentd-${time.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')}
        logstash_format true
        logstash_prefix fluentd
        logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
      </match>
    </label>
```

How can I do?